# Unity3D scene not rendering objects in Game mode

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have three objects in a scene: a grass cube, a sky cube, and a brick cube. All the objects are in the same layer, and it appears that they are correctly aligned in space to show properly. Actually, the camera preview shows them right, but then in Game mode somehow one of the cubes, the sky in this case, always shows in front and overlaps the brick.

What bothers me specially is that in the tiny Camera Preview window it's showing correctly, but then in the Game it's not.

Any idea why could this be happening?

http://prntscr.com/6iez5a

[image: This is how it looks]

Comment: Have you tried pausing the game, and seeing where the skybox is? Is it still where it is supposed to be? Or has it moved in front?

Comment: Yes, It happens also when it's not running and the objects are always where they're supposed to be. Actually, they don't move at all.

Comment: Ave you tried deleting the camera from the scene, then adding it back? Are there any scripts attached to it or any of the boxes? What are the settings for the camera object? What different settings/variables have you tried?